# YandexMapkit - как проверить вхождение точки в область?

Tags: android, ios, yandex-maps-api, flutter, yandexmapkit

Пишу приложение на flutter, использую этот [плагин](https://github.com/Unact/yandex_mapkit). Есть регион(область доставки) - массив точек с координатами(широта/долгота), нужно проверить входит ли произвольная точка(широта/долгота) в эту область. Поиском по исходникам подобных методов не нашел. Возможно можно использовать методы из нативного кода(android, ios). или есть методы апи для этого?
нашел только [это](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/archive/doc/jsapi/2.0/ref/reference/IPolygonGeometryAccess.html#method_detail__contains). но это для java script.в общем любые советы - буду благодарен.

Comment: Такие вопросы следует задавать в issues библиотеки, а не на stackoverflow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном плагине нет такой возможно, так как нативные реализации яндекс карт не поддерживают такой функционал. Можно использовать такой алгоритм, сам его использовал для похожей задачи.

```
function inside(point, vs) {
    
    var x = point[0], y = point[1];
    
    var inside = false;
    for (var i = 0, j = vs.length - 1; i < vs.length; j = i++) {
        var xi = vs[i][0], yi = vs[i][1];
        var xj = vs[j][0], yj = vs[j][1];
        
        var intersect = ((yi > y) != (yj > y))
            && (x < (xj - xi) * (y - yi) / (yj - yi) + xi);
        if (intersect) inside = !inside;
    }
    
    return inside;
};
```